# best way to render Watch frames on iPhone without grinding to a halt

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

[image: interface]

I'm trying to extend what apple watch can do by rendering `UIImage` 'frames' and then setting them on my `WKInterfaceImage` every 500 milliseconds (2 frames per second).

My plan is to try render 8bit style games that don't need high detail or frame rates and then get arrow buttons on the watch app to direct how the game state changes.

So I have a Game class that has a 'tick' method which returns a `UIImage`. Each call to 'tick' will proceed the game by a single point. Think Tetris where each 'tick' of the game moves the falling blocks by one block space downwards. The game proceeds by 'ticks' until there is interaction from the user. Upon call to rotate the block, I am telling the Game class to rotate left or right when the next 'tick' happens. Here are the relevant parts of my `WKInterfaceController` class below.

```
- (void)willActivate
{
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    NSLog(@"%@ will activate", self);

    // wait 2 seconds until game 'starts'
    [self performSelector:@selector(timerFired) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.];
}

- (void)timerFired
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.theImage setImage:[self.game tick]];

        [self performSelector:@selector(timerFired) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
    });
}

- (IBAction)leftButtonPressed
{
    self.game.futureMove = FutureMoveAntiClockWise;
}
- (IBAction)rightButtonPressed
{
    self.game.futureMove = FutureMoveClockWise;
}
```

Now, amazingly all that code works great - for a few seconds. Then it all gets slower and slower and more and more behind (in terms of frames). After 10 seconds or so pressing the rotate left or right buttons only shows up on the rendered `UIImage` a few seconds later.

The watch app starts off rendering maybe 30 frames a second (if I wanted it to), and then crawls slower and slower and ultimately stops. Is there a better way to reliably `setImage` on a `WKInterfaceImage` repeatedly without it slowing down?

I'm so close!!

Comment: You may profile your application with Allocation Tool. Then check with Call Trees which method or thread is taking more memory or execution time. If you have customised getters for theImage and game objects then make sure they are optimised and not creating objects on every method call. It can be a delay from tick method. App profiling may give you some clue about your problem.

Comment: I'd caution you about your approach, as there have been mentions of games in the developer forums that require fast transmission/response from the watch that have been rejected. The rejections seems to indicate that anything that updates more than once every second or two and/or requires a fast response doesn't work well on the actual hardware. Might want to wait for an actual Watch to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you comments. After updating to Xcode 6.3 it works fine and doesn't lag but I will heed @MikeSwanson and expect Apple to reject my app :(.